# Using a zsh function in find?

Tags: find, osx, zsh

I'm on OS X and have defined a function called `finderpackage` that tries to determine if a folder is in fact a "package" (also, somewhat erroneously, known as a "bundle") according to the Finder.

My intended use for this was to limit `find` from descending into such folders which is sometimes useful.

One application would be finding the size of files in a subtree while treating apps, frameworks, document formats that are really folders, and similar as single "files", just like Finder would:

`find . -xdev \( -exec finderpackage {} \; -exec du -sk {} \; -prune \) -or \( -type f -exec du -k {} \; \)`

However, this example does not work as `find` complains: `find: finderpackage: No such file or directory`

Can I not use a zsh function in this way?

(Of course I can rewrite it as a script, I'm just curious if I have missed something about how functions are used?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

functions are features of the shell language. `/bin/zsh` is a command that is an interpreter of the `zsh` language. `find` is another command which is intended to find files. With `-exec`, it can *execute* a command. A zsh function is not a command.

`find` would need to have `zsh` interpret the code in the function. For that it would need to invoke `zsh` in a way that tells it  to load the code of that function and run it with the file it has found. It can be done, like with:

```
find ... -exec zsh -c "(){$functions[finderpackage];}"' "$@"' zsh {} \; ...
```

(above, we're invoking `zsh`  with an inline script (with `-c`) whose content uses an anonymous function (`(){code} args`) where the code is copied from that of the `finderpackage` function in the shell that invokes that `find` command).

But that means invoking one `zsh` command per file which is going to be terribly inefficient.

`zsh` globbing has recursive capabilities and qualifiers that make it almost equivalent to `find` but unfortunately, one thing it is missing is the ability to control how the directory traversal is done in an arbitrary fashion.

You can prune directories based on their name, like:

```
setopt extendedglob
print -rl -- (^*.pkg/)#*(.)
```

To *prune* the `*.pkg` directories. But you couldn't prune directories that are *old* or contain this or that file for instance.  For that you'd have to resort to doing the directory traversal by hand.

One thing you could do, though that's not going to be very efficient either is to interact with `find` as a `coproc` and use its `-ok`:

```
coproc stdbuf -o0 find . -type f -exec printf 'f:%s\0' {} \; -o \
  -type d -exec printf 'd:%s\0' {} \; -ok true \; -prune 2> /dev/null
while IFS=: read -rpd '' type file; do
  case $type in
    (d)
      if finderpackage $file; then
        print -p y
        du -sk $file
      else
        print -p n
      fi;;
    (f)
      du -k $file
  esac
done
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was just thinking that, since find is executing in zsh, it should be able to get the definition (or the shell replacing it with a temporary script or something). 

And you are right, spawning a new shell for each file is ridiculously expensive. As I said, I'll just rewrite it as a script instead. 

Your last suggestion does not work, by the way, most "packages" (which has nothing to do with software distribution in OS X) are defined via metadata so (apart from a handful of known extensions) you need to query `mdls`to know if it is a package.

Comment: BTW: the latest version of `bosh` can call a shell function from `find`. This is because `find` is a builtin command in `bosh` implemented via `libfind` and libfind now supports a new primary called `-call` that allows to call the shell without an `execl()` but by directly calling the shell interpreter. This is 40x faster than using `-exec` as long as only shell internals are used in that callback.